# Setting the baseRoot for mocha babel-register: "Cannot find module 'atoms/histogram',"

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, babeljs, enzyme, babel-register

I've a project with this current layout:

```
├── atoms
│   ├── histogram
├── molecules
│   ├── many-histograms
```

And since I didn't want to use ugly relative paths in my imports, I've set the `paths` property for the Browserify.

So in `molecules/many-histograms/index.jsx`, I'm able to:

```
import Histogram from 'atoms/histogram';
```

It works nicely in development, but running the tests seems to be dying for that import. It says: `Cannot find module 'atoms/histogram'`

My current config for mocha is as follows:

```
gulp.src(config.js.tests, {read: false})
    .pipe(mocha({
        compilers: {
            js: "babel-register ../../_dev_tools/test_setup.js"
        },
        reporter: 'min'
    }).on('error', reporters.testError));
```

How can I set the proper import root for Mocha or Babel?